# Single File Access by certain domains

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, cross-domain

I was wondering if there is an “easy” way to protect a file from begin access from all domains…

Let say that I want only a few domains to use my script so they put in their HTML
From domain yourdomain.com you write

If your domain is in our “allow” access then you can use it, if not, then show an error or just nothing…

Is that possible with PHP?

Or do I have to use .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straight forward way is to use a .htaccess file. These files typically take IP address and not domains. The code below would only allow from 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 and anything else would be denied.

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 1.1.1.1
 allow from 2.2.2.2
</Limit>
```

Comment: Thank you cogsmos, problem is, that by doing that, it denied access to every body else for the whole website... I may be doing something wrong... may be I have to put the .htaccess inside the folder where my script is... I'm going to try that... I really don't want to use ioncube...

Comment: You are absolutely correct, if you put that htaccess file in the root directory of your website everyone is going to be blocked. You may have refactor your website slightly but it would be easiest to put the protected files in a subdirectory and have the htaccess file in there. Don't forget that it is recursive for all other subdirectories under the one you put it in.